# How to turn off geojson layers in Leaflet when the site starts?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, visibility

I have a problem with my geojson layers. When I lunch my site they are all switched on, but I don't want to. Is there any solution to have lunched only one layer when my site starts, not the all one? Here is the simple example what I want https://jsfiddle.net/expedio/dtLyvffg/

And this is the code with my layers:

```js
var controlLayers = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

$.getJSON("data/Zabudowa.geoJSON", function(geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    style: function(feature) {
      return {
        'weight': 0,
        'fillColor': 'brown',
        'fillOpacity': 1
      }
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      var popupText = "Numer obiektu: " + feature.properties.OBJECTID + "<br>Sposob uzytkowania: " + feature.properties.type + "<br><a href='" + feature.properties.url + "'>More info</a>";
      layer.bindPopup(popupText);
    }
  }).addTo(map);
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Zabudowa');
});


controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Drogi');
});

var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  iconUrl: 'icons/cemetery-24.png'

});
$.getJSON("data/miejsca_pamieci.geoJSON", function(geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
      return new L.Marker(latLng, {
        icon: new myIcon({
          iconUrl: 'icons/cemetery-24.png',
          iconSize: [24, 24],
          iconAnchor: [12, 24],
          popupAnchor: [0, -24]
        })
      })
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup("Opis: " + feature.properties.Opis)
    }
  }).addTo(map);
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Miejsca_pamieci');
});

var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  iconUrl: 'icons/accessdenied.png'

});

$.getJSON("data/Fotografie.geoJSON", function(geojson) {
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
      return new L.Marker(latLng, {
        icon: new myIcon({
          iconUrl: 'icons/accessdenied.png',
          iconSize: [32, 37],
          iconAnchor: [16, 37],
          popupAnchor: [0, -37]
        })
      })
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name, {
        maxWidth: "auto"
      })
    }
  }).addTo(map);
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'Fotografie');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do not add your layers to the map (remove the `.addTo(map)` after your `L.geoJson()` factories), but only to your `controlLayers` Layers Control.

Comment: Thanks! It was so simple that I couldn't even imagine. It's becouse I'm green in javascripts and all the stuff but I'm learning every day something new.