# Leaflet map with toggleable overlays - reading in data from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, geojson

I have a Leaflet map with several sets of points read in from a PostgreSQL database. I would like to make each of these collections an overlay that I can toggle on and off. Without having overlays I can read in the information from the PostgreSQL database and display the points.

I have managed to create an empty overlay (no points display), or can display points and overlays if they the points are not read in from the database. I am having trouble combining the features.

I know this has been asked many times - but I have not been able to implement any of the solutions, nor get any of the examples working. I am new very new to Leaflet (and all the associated coding/programs).

I have tried to follow [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207738/how-to-turn-off-geojson-layers-in-leaflet-when-the-site-starts) but I do not know what their GeoJSON files look like - and have not been able to adapt the code.

Here is my attempt at following the above solution but with my data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Test Map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
  crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
  crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  #map {
    height:800px;
  }
  </style>

  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function init(){
    var osmLink = "<a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org'>Open StreetMap</a>"
    var map = new L.map('map').setView([ -20.91, 142.70], 5);
    osmMap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + osmLink, maxZoom: 18,}).addTo(map);
    attrLink = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.'
    attrLinkToner = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.';
    var terrainMap = L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',{
      attribution: attrLink,
      maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
    var baseLayers = {
      "Open Street Map":osmMap, "Stamen Terrain": terrainMap
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

    showLayers(map);

    function showLayers(map) {

      var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "./images/frog.png",
        iconSize: [24,24],
        iconAnchor: [12,24]
      });

      var controlLayers = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

      $.getJSON("getData.php", function(data) {
        var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
          style: function(feature) {
            return {
              'weight': 0,
              'fillColor': 'brown',
              'fillOpacity': 1
            }
          },
          onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            var popupText = "Popup Text";
            layer.bindPopup(popupText);
          }
        }).addTo(map);
        controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'ExampleLayer');
      });

    } // end of function showLayers

  }// end of function init
  </script>
</head>
<h1>Page heading</h1>
<body onload=init()>
  <div id = "map"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The sample of the output from running `getData.php` is

```
[{"id":13,"siteID":"ClevelandBay","siteLatitude":"-19.22","siteLongitude":"146.92","studyTitle":"Seagrass Abundance","classification":"GroupA"}, {"id":5,"siteID":"KnappCreek","siteLatitude":"-28.1","siteLongitude":"152.8","studyTitle":"Gully erosion","classification":"GroupA"}]
```

I am not sure that the link is the right approach to take - so I'm happy with alternatives.

The following bit of code correctly shows the markers on the map (with the popup information that I will include once I get the basics working)

```
  $.getJSON("getData.php",function(data){
    for (let i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
      let location = new L.LatLng(data[i].siteLatitude, data[i].siteLongitude);
      let marker = new L.Marker(location, {
        icon: modelIcon,
        title: 'thetitle' });

        let studyTitle = data[i].studyTitle
        let siteID = data[i].siteID;

        let content = "<h2>" + studyTitle + "</h2>" + "<p>" + siteID + "</p>" + "<p> <b>" + "</b></p>";
        marker.bindPopup(content, {
          maxWidth: '400'
        });
        marker.addTo(map);
      } 
    }  
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. The issue you're having is related to the data you're passing in to the  `L.geoJson()` method.

Refer to the Leaflet docs [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson), you can see it accepts GeoJson object and options.

You must convert your data from the getData.php to geojson, something like:

```
geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id": id,
        "siteId": siteId,
        "classification": classification,
         "studyTitle": studyTitle
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [siteLongitude, siteLatitude]
    }
};
```

Which you can then pass into L.geoJson(data).

UPDATE:
You can loop through the data returned from data.php and create geojson objects from there.

```
var data = [{"id":13,"siteID":"ClevelandBay","siteLatitude":"-19.22","siteLongitude":"146.92","studyTitle":"Seagrass Abundance","classification":"GroupA"}, {"id":5,"siteID":"KnappCreek","siteLatitude":"-28.1","siteLongitude":"152.8","studyTitle":"Gully erosion","classification":"GroupA"}];

    var collection = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i +=1) {
        collection.push({
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": data[i].id,
            "siteId": data[i].siteId,
            "classification": data[i].classification,
             "studyTitle": data[i].studyTitle
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [data[i].siteLongitude, data[i].siteLatitude]
        }
        });
    }
```

Please see the forked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obhkugey/) from the example you provided.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Owen - but I cannot figure out how to incorporate this.  I looked at the docs, but I really don't understand even the basics.  I've tried a few different things and the best I could achieve is an empty layer (map but no points).

Comment: @Esme_ I've provided an updated answer. I hope this helps you solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks Owen - I was able to get the example working, but unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.  I suspect that the example I pointed to wasn't the right approach after all.  I'll keep hunting.

Comment: @Esme_ No worries, can you update your question? I'm still unsure what the problem is you're trying to solve. The example I provided creates a leaflet overlay layer that can be toggled on and off, which answers your original question.

Comment: Turns out part of my problem was with the getJSON call - I just didn't realise when I asked the question that this was a problem.  I think I've almost got it sorted and will update when I've either got it working properly or have a clear understanding of exactly what I can't figure out.  Thanks so much for your help - you solved part of my problem, which meant I could finally see some of the other things I'd done wrong.

Comment: @Esme_ could you figure out the solution?